# Javascript header change transition

Tags: javascript, css

I have googled repeatedly and can not find a working answer to this query...

Website: http://miners-arms.wearepixel.co.uk/job-vacancies/

When you scroll down the page of this site the header changes. What I would like to know is, how can I add a fade transition when the change takes place?

Similar to this site: https://www.venndigital.co.uk/technology/

Many thanks,

Comment: Take a look at these [bootstrap templates](http://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/agency/). Just click live preview or download the sourcecode (they are free).

Answer (score 1):

With this script:

```
    $(window).scroll(function() {       
        var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (scroll >= 110) {
                 //$("#headertop").addClass("parallax-window-top");
                 $("#headertop").fadeIn(200);
            } else {
                 //$("#headertop").removeClass("parallax-window-top");
                 $("#headertop").fadeIn(200);
            } 
    });
```

Comment: You should comment the original code and uncomment the working one.

Comment: sorry but I didn't understand :( @SideriteZackwehdex

Comment: In the block above, your solution is in the commented code. He is already doing the toggling of the CSS class.

Comment: As you can see from our code we attempted that solution but it doesn't work. The class isn't loaded which is required.

Answer (score 1):

You are toggling a class called parallax-window-top:

```
.parallax-window-top {
  min-height: 35px;
  background: #fff;
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 99999;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #23bcbf;
  height: 60px;

  transition: display .5s ease;
  -webkit-transition: display .50s ease;
  -moz-transition: display .50s ease;
  -o-transition: display .50s ease;
}
```

As you see, the display is the only thing that you want to transition. I think that opacity or height would be more appropriate. But also, this transition doesn't exist until you set the class. So when you toggle it off, you also remove the transition, which I think would make it fail. If display would be on and off based on the class, even if you transition opacity or height, you still couldn't see any change.

Here is a fiddle with a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/kas6r6rg/

I added a height and different transition times for opacity and height: https://jsfiddle.net/kas6r6rg/1/

Notice that removing the height value from the original CSS disables the effect. That is because transitions work on continuous properties, like numbers. Display is discreet: 'block','none'; there are no intermediate values between them.

So in your case, just change the CSS like this:

```
#headertop {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: visible;
    transition: opacity .5s ease;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .50s ease;
    -moz-transition: opacity .50s ease;
    -o-transition: opacity .50s ease;
    opacity: 0;
}
.parallax-window-top {
    min-height: 35px;
    background: #fff;
    opacity: 1 !important;
    z-index: 99999;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #23bcbf;
    height: 60px;
    /* transition: display .5s ease; 
     -webkit-transition: display .50s ease; 
    -moz-transition: display .50s ease;
    -o-transition: display .50s ease;*/
}
```

Comment: I understand. This is why I was wondering if there was a javascript solution. Many thanks

Comment: You don't need a javascript solution. Just add the transition CSS to #headertop and use opacity instead of display. I've updated my answer.

Comment: It does kind of work: http://miners-arms.wearepixel.co.uk but still has issues. - Thank you for your time on this Siderite

Answer (score 0):

Ok this one works form me:

```
<!DOCTYPE html >
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Tst</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
    <style type="text/css">
        .content{
            height:1600px;
        }
        .parallax-window-top {
          min-height: 35px;
          background: #fff;
          opacity: 1;
          z-index: 99999;
          border-bottom: 1px solid #23bcbf;
          height: 60px;

          transition: display .5s ease;
          -webkit-transition: display .50s ease;
          -moz-transition: display .50s ease;
          -o-transition: display .50s ease;
          display:block;
        }
        #headertop {
            position: fixed;
            width: 100%;
            overflow: visible;
            background-color:#808080;
            display:none;
        }
        body {
            margin: 0px;
            padding:0px;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(window).scroll(function () {
            var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
            if (scroll >= 110) {
                //$("#headertop").addClass("parallax-window-top");
                $("#headertop").fadeIn(200);
            } else {
                //$("#headertop").removeClass("parallax-window-top");
                $("#headertop").fadeOut(200);
            }
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="headertop" >
        HEADER
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        VERY LONG PAGE<br />
        VERY LONG PAGE<br />
        VERY LONG PAGE<br />
        VERY LONG PAGE<br />
        VERY LONG PAGE<br />
        VERY LONG PAGE<br />
        VERY LONG PAGE<br />
        VERY LONG PAGE<br />
    </div>


</body>



</html>
```